# Insert byte slice into sqlite blob

Tags: go, sqlite

I try to insert a slice of bytes into a sqlite3 database, using github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3.

Data:

```
thmbnail := [255 216 255 219 0 132 ...]
```

Create statement:

```
sqlStmt := `
create table result (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, fname TEXT, path TEXT, 
size INTEGER, fMDate TEXT, fUUID TEXT, fSHA1 TEXT, fPRONOM TEXT, fNSRL INTEGER, fTHMB BLOB);
pragma journal_mode=WAL;
delete from result;
`
```

Insert:

```
func addEntryDB(stmt *sql.Stmt, entry fileMD) {

    _, err := stmt.Exec(nil, entry.fName, entry.fPath, entry.fSize, entry.fMDate,
    entry.fUUID, entry.fSHA1, entry.fPRONOM, entry.fNSRL, entry.fTHMB)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Problem: Only the first four bytes of thmbnail are inserted. I suppose this might be related to the 0 byte on the fifth position.

How can the whole []byte be inserted?

Comment: This might be related. But the bug should be fixed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452538/convert-blob-to-image-in-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It sat before the monitor.The data was inserted actually. Sqlite client handles the blob as text and terminates printing at the "0". Inspecting the database with sqlitebrowser showed the complete entry.